# When creating game object position is wrong when set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code

```
GameObject tocreate = new GameObject ("newsstory1");
    tocreate.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
    tocreate.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = newsbuilten;

    tocreate.transform.parent = notifcationparents.transform;
    tocreate.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (6, 6, 0);
    tocreate.transform.position = new Vector3 (80, 18 ,5);
```

My problem is when I run this the game object is in the wrong position; here is the image

[image: All help is appreciated!]

Comment: Position is relative to the `transform.parent` maybe? What absolute position does the `notificationparents.transform` object have?

Comment: 0, 0, 0 is the vector 3 position

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Don't worry about the position you see in the Editor. It is happening because you are setting the parent GameObject.

Let's say that the parent Object(`notifcationparents`) is at the position of:

`5`, `10`, `30`

Then you create a new GameObject named *"newsstory1"* and set its position to:

`80`, `18`, `5`

That new GameObject will move to that position but you will see:

`75`, `8`, `-25`

as its position in the Editor because that's what (`80`, `18`, `5`) **--** (`5`, `10`, `30`) is. You are just seeing a position relative to its parent GameObject. That wouldn't happen if there is no parent GameObject.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use transform.parent, instead use transform.SetParent().
Also, first set the position of the game object and then set it's parent using transform.SetParent(parent, true).